# current_time function incorrect in plugin and PHP, not in WordPress admin

Tags: php, server, timestamp, timezones

I had to reboot my server due to recurring server errors (which I couldn't find a reason for). Since rebooting, echoing `current_time( 'timestamp', true )` shows the time as 14 hours before my current timezone (GMT). As does echoing `time()`. However, if I go to “Settings > General” in WordPress, the correct time and timezone are showing.

This was all working perfectly before the reboot. How do I fix this? I have tried setting the PHP timezone via an .ini file, which made no difference. The server itself is showing the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

`true` is for GMT time, try removing it.

```
current_time( 'timestamp' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/